# How to get value in a web page dialog

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint,there is a default WebPart called RSS Viewer,and if you click the "XSL Editor" button in the ToolPart of RSS Viewer,it will popup a web page dialog,and you can edit the information and save it.
I am doing something that needs such function,I click the "Edit" button in the ToolPart of my WebPart,it popups a web page dialog.I wrote it like this:

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "window.showModalDialog('/_layouts/MyWebPart/sample.html')");
```

So,how to save or get the strings in the popuped web page dialog to my WebPart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you rely on jQuery dialog http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog? If you can link jQuery into your webpart, then take a look at this event in it: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close. That might be useful for you. This will require your solution architecture change a bit.

Or you don't want to change the architecture you could analyse the Save button of the modal window that popups in a web debugger like FireBug.

Comment: I try to use the jQuery dialog,I click the button in the ToolPart,it shows the dialog,but the dialog disappeared quickly.Do you know why?

Comment: may be your button causes a post back that reloads the page after the dialog appears? if so you should use client only button.

Comment: Year,you are right,the button is a server control,I replaced it with a html button,and it works.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code for working with a dialog in SharePoint. When you close your dialog you pass the dialog result object that will be used as an argument in your "host" page

```
var webUrl = "<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID='webUrl' runat='server' EncodeMethod='EcmaScriptStringLiteralEncode' />" + "/_layouts/IC/PhoneBookPicker/SelectItem.aspx";

var dialogTitle = "<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID='dialogTitle' runat='server' EncodeMethod='EcmaScriptStringLiteralEncode' />";

var displayValueClientID = "<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID='displayValueClientID' runat='server' EncodeMethod='EcmaScriptStringLiteralEncode' />";

var hiddenValueClientID = "<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID='hiddenValueClientID' runat='server' EncodeMethod='EcmaScriptStringLiteralEncode' />";


function openPhoneBookPickerSearchDialog() {

var options = {

title: dialogTitle,

width: 600,

height: 435,

url: webUrl,

displayValue: document.getElementById(displayValueClientID).innerHTML,

hiddenValue: document.getElementById(hiddenValueClientID).value,

dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, IC_modalDialogClosedCallback)

};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

}


function IC_modalDialogClosedCallback(result, value) {

if (result == 1) {

document.getElementById(hiddenValueClientID).value = value.hiddenValue;

document.getElementById(displayValueClientID).innerHTML = value.displayValue;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog can only be used in SharePoint 2010.I added the commonShowModalDialog function to a button,but I don't know how to save the contents in the webpage dialog when it popups.